# How to solve 'GitRepository not found' error in FluxCD?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, gitlab, fluxcd

I am trying to use Azure kuberenetes cluster and FluxCD to connect to a repository named `realtimeapp-infra` in Gitlab. I created the source and kustomization `.yaml` files in another repo `training-setup`, but getting the following error when I use `flux get kustomizations` in `cmd`. I was getting the same error with GitHub also. (I am new to both FluxCD and Kubernetes.)

[image: error after using flux get kustomizations]

EDIT: The problem was solved. It was due to no master branch in the repository, and I did not have access to create the master branch. After the owner created it, the issue was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

Did you connected to repository `realtimeapp-infra` as a GitRepository inside flux with username & credentials? This is a own CRD type coming with flux = `kubectl get gitrepository -A`